# $(echo "cd ..") Command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

Good ol' `-bash: cd ..: command not found`.

I have a script I wrote to traverse up to a named directory. It had been working and now for the life of me I don't know what's changed.

```bash
$ type up
up is a function
up () 
{ 
    local arg="$@";
    if [ -z "$arg" ]; then
        cd ..;
        return 1;
    fi;
    local arr=();
    local sep='/';
    local IFS="$sep";
    local DIRS;
    read -ra DIRS <<< "$(pwd)";
    for ((i=${#DIRS[@]}-1; i>=0; i-- ))
    do
        if [ "${DIRS[i]}" = "$arg" ]; then
            local first=${arr[0]};
            arr=("${arr[@]:1}");
            $(printf "%s" "cd $first" "${arr[@]/#/$sep}" && echo "/");
            return 1;
        else
            arr+=('..');
        fi;
    done;
    echo "Directory \"$arg\" could not be found in path. Check spelling and try again." 1>&2;
    return 0
}
```

Steps

1. if no arg is passed, go up a directory
2. if an arg is passed:

   1. grab the `pwd` and split on `/`
   2. iterate over the list of dirs walking from the back of the queue
   3. if the current dir doesn't match the arg, add `..` to a list
   4. if the dir matches the command line arg, unpack `..`, delimit with `/`, and execute the string as a command

      ```bash
      printf "%s" "cd $first" "${arr[@]/#/$sep}" && echo "/"

      # printf "%s" "cd $first" :   prints 'cd ..' (command & the first placeholder) 
      # "${arr[@]/#/$sep}"      :   prints the remaining '..' joined by '/'
      # echo "/"                :   adds a trailing '/' to the relative path 
      #                               which could have been included in the 
      #                               previous step but separated for comprehension

      # Given, pwd = /Users/dev/workspace/project/foo
      # `up workspace` navigates to 'cd ../../'
      ```

### Debugging (from the terminal)

```bash
> cd ..
# works as expected

> $(echo "cd ..")
# works as expected --> maybe something with the "/" is breaking it?

> $('cd ..')
# -bash: cd ..: command not found

> $('cd ../')
# -bash: cd ../: No such file or directory

> which cd
# /usr/bin/cd

> echo $PATH
# /usr/bin

> type cd
# cd is a shell builtin

> alias cd
# -bash: alias: cd: not found

> shopt expand_aliases
# expand_aliases    on
```

Unsetting most of the environment variables (e.g., CDPATH) or opening a shell with a clean environment (i.e. `env -i bash --noprofile --norc`) did not help in bash3.2 on OSX.

### Comments

My bash is a little rusty, so feel free to give pointers on a better way, that's as maintainable. I know `return` may not be necessary (or correct) and I've seen some `find` implementations, which were probably more efficient, but more difficult to follow.

Comment: if you want to execute `cd ..` to change up one directory, then do that, don't wrap it in a subshell to capture its output in a string, which is what `$(   )` does.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, I do that in the first `if` block, but in the remaining logic it can have a variable amount of relative paths (see last comment in Step #4 for an example).  It might be `cd ../../../../../`.

Comment: Like Marcus said, those command substitutions aren't helpful. Just build the directory name in a variable (e.g. with `dir=$(printf ...)`, or `printf -v dir ...`), and then run `cd "$dir"`.

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu I'm having trouble following or maybe I left an error in the example (I've been bouncing around).  The effective code that it tries to run is something like `$(echo "cd ../../../")` which results in `cd ..: command not found`.  The debug statements are just for confirmation.  I've also tried outputting to a variable with `-v out` and that didn't prove fruitful.  I'm partially troubled because this was working at one point.

Comment: I don't think I saved to a variable without the command and cd-ing on the path. I'll try that!

Comment: @ilkkachu that worked.  Very bone-headed of me :P  Thank you so much.  Appreciate you both.  Who wants to create an answer so I can accept for the credit?

Comment: @Mike, right, now I saw it. Strike what I first said, it's the modified `IFS` that breaks it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(echo "cd ..")` runs the shell command `echo "cd .."` (that is, the command `echo` with the single argument `cd ..`), takes the output (`cd ..`), splits that on whitespace (and globs, though that doesn't matter here), gets the two words `cd` and `..`, and runs the `cd` with the argument `..`. That's a convoluted and error-prone way of just running the shell command `cd ..`.

**Except** that here, you've set `IFS` to a slash, so the word splitting part *doesn't split on whitespace, but on slashes*.

So, when you do e.g. `$(echo "cd ../..")`, the result of the command substitution is split not as `cd`, `../..`, but as `cd ..`, `..`. The space now being part of the command name here as if you entered `"cd .." ..` on the shell command line.

It's likely better not to rely on word-splitting to get it right (especially since it'll break the moment your directory names contain whitespace), but to keep the command and argument separate. Build the directory name in a variable and use that, i.e.:

```
dir=$(printf "../..")
cd -- "$dir"
```

Or perhaps rather

```
printf -v dir "../.."
cd -- "$dir"
```

---

Also, you might not need that `printf` there. You can use `"${arr[*]}"` to get the array elements joined with the first character of `IFS`, so with `IFS=/`, it would join them with slashes.

E.g.:

```
arr=(.. .. ..)
IFS=/
dir="${arr[*]}"
```

sets `dir` to `../../..`.

Comment: That makes much more sense to me.  I was refactoring the IFS for local scoping.  Per your recommendation, I still prefer to stick the output in a variable, but I knew what I had (cd as part of the print string) was working and I couldn't figure out why it broke.  Thank you so much.  Now I can get back to actual work after this this 2 hour detour :) Can I buy you a cup of coffee?

Comment: It seems I need 15 creds to upvote. I'll make a todo to come back to boost this answer too.

Comment: @Mike, haha, I did once think about getting a buymeacoffee.com account or such, just to see what would happen. But then I couldn't be bothered to actually do it. Don't worry about the upvotes either, writing here is just a hobby. (Ok, well, maybe it also has to do with an addiction induced by gamification and imaginary internet points, but anyway...)

Comment: @Mike, didn't you day in your question that it had been working before and you don't know what changed? So you **did** change something, you just didn't think it was relevant?

Comment: @aviro It's not that I didn't think it was relevant, but that I didn't think anything had changed. In this case, it's been some time since I've done bash scripting, I needed a duck or another set of eyes -- expert eyes -- of you all here.  I had briefly coded it up on OSX and Linux -- not repo checked (first mistake) -- and never encountered an error on either.  When I came back to OSX, I started experiencing the error.  At that point I don't think I modified anything. Was I using it differently?--I'm not sure.

Comment: When I went into "debug mode", I changed a bunch of things.  Various permutations that I'm sure included something relevant, but what?  The IFS was one of many changes, and I think modified only after the error had incurred (I originally had it inline `IFS="/" read -ra ...`).  I'll have to review the other system to see if I'm handling the IFS the same way.  If I made an addendum it would be that I'm not sure what changed...and when.  The heart of my question was wanting to understand where the error now existed, which @ilkkachu graciously pointed out. The `${arr[*]}` was a nice little bonus.

Comment: @ilkkachu Not to get too meta, but I understand the gamification :D I was a longtime SO user and once my account hit 50k (in the early days), I started newer accounts, but really my joy helping others.  These days I like to buy coffees out of appreciation :D